# How do you find the null to null bandwidth for the signal below?

Tags: signal-analysis, sampling, power-spectral-density, continuous-signals, quantization

[image]

My tutor does not explain it very well. Can someone please explain to me the reasoning and what null to null bandwidth actually is?

Comment: It's asking to find where the first zeroes occur in the spectrum. You already have the expression for the spectrum so set it to zero and solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) $\mathbb{sinc}(x)$ is the Fourier Transform of a Rectangular pulse.
Its zeros are located at non-zero integers of $x$:
$$\text{sinc}(x) = 0$$

> for $x = 1,2,\dots$

Therefore, if your spectrum can be expressed as $\text{sinc}(Bx)$, the first zero occurs at $1/B$, the second at $2/B$, etc, and the corresponding time-domain signal is a Rectangular Pulse with Bandwidth $2 * 1/B$.

In your case, the bandwidth is $2 /(4\times10^{-4}) = 5000\, \text{Hz}$

Comment: The answer in the tutorial is given as 2500hz. And when I asked why its not 5000 the lecturer said only to consider the positive frequency part. Is he right?

Comment: @MALLU It is a common convention that for real signals (not complex) that the BW is given as the 1 sided bandwidth - the other side is implied due to the frequency symmetry required by a real signal. Once you start dealing with basebanded (complex) signals the bandwidth will be the full 2 sided value since the signal is no longer symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

The following MATLAB script is a solution to your question

```
clear all;close all;clc
```

**1. `fzero` only returns 1 zero**

```
syms f
y1=@(f) 10*sinc(4e-4*f);

x0=fzero(y1,0)
```

$x_0=-2500$

$\text{sinc}$ has more than 1 zero but now we know where to look, because `fzero` found the 1st zero after $f = 0$ and this is half the interval you have been asked for.

**2.**

```
x0=100000;
x=[-x0:.01:x0];
y=10*sinc(.00004*x);
figure
plot(x,y)
grid on
xlabel('x')
axis([-x0 x0 -2.2 10])

y2=abs(y);
n1=find(y2<.000001)

hold on
plot(x(n1),zeros(1,numel(n1)),'or')
```

**3. the answer is**

```
BW=x(n1(5))-x(n1(4)) % answer
```

$5000$

```
plot([x(n1(4)) x(n1(5))],[0 0],'LineWidth',2,'Color','r')
```

[image]

this matches with half the result of

```
abs(2*x0)
```

$5000$

Comment: Not a math-based answer, which I'm guessing is what the OP was looking for, however this is a nice visualization that will help the OP.

Comment: might want to modify your code a little, you’re doing 4.10e-5 instead of 4.10e-4 ;)

Comment: The answer in the tute is given as 2500hz. And when I asked why its not 5000 the lecturer said only to consider the positive frequency part. Is he right?

Comment: Also thanks for the visualization mate. Appreciate it

Comment: Yes 2500hz is right if you only consider the positive frequency part…

Comment: Having said this, as politely as possible, you could have pointed out to the tutor that when ignoring negative frequencies, just for the sake of saving paper, or a more concise display, thenthe spectrum has to be multipled by 2 in order to preserve signal power, to avoid actually modifying the signal for a display purposes only. Rewording: halving real signals spectrum (f>0 only) and not doubling signal amplitudes implies power loss, that for academic purposes, many times doesn't really matter.

Comment: MALLU thanks for the feedback. Your tutor just showed how important is to break any ambiguity before answering, like whether is f>0 spectrum to be considered only? or should we stick to Fourier transform output? the obvious answer is because the signal is baseband then f>0 only. But even baseband, the signal could have imaginary component, and then it wouldn't be any longer symetrical.  Amd if the sinc had been centered at let's say 100kHz then the null to null would be 5000. But because it's a baseband real signal the academic answer is 2500. To accademia give them 
 anwswers to score.

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that $\text{sinc}(x)$ is zero for all arguments $x$ that are nonzero integers, so the problem reduces to "what values of $f$ yield the nonzero integers closest to zero, that is, $1$ and $-1$?"

The answer to that question is $f = \pm\text{2500 Hz}$, and the distance between them is $\text{5000 Hz}$.

Comment: The answer in the tute is given as 2500hz. And when I asked why its not 5000 the lecturer said only to consider the positive frequency part. Is he right?